# How to establish a TCP connection

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to implement something that could send data from a not-ROS-running System(A) to a ROS-running System(Z) and later sending data from Z back to A using a TCP connection (using socket). I was looking for something on that page http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/TCPROS but it is not clear for me. Are there any tutorials/codes to launch a server on a ROS-running System and listening for clients? Are there any packages that allow to implement TCP communication?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250564/how-to-establish-a-tcp-connection/) by [Cayero](https://answers.ros.org/users/27919/cayero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluesnow](https://answers.ros.org/users/41065/bluesnow/) on 2019-04-26**:
Hello, did you solve your problem? Now i have the same Problem. I really want to know what you have done. And i can not run the code from https://github.com/abhinavjain241/comm_tcp in ROS. I look forward to your answer.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-09**:
This is already answered. However, I would like to add my words here. The comment above refers to a code that creates and manages a socket all by itself. It would be better to do this low-level task by an external library. For example, [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/) is a robust and famous library with bindings in many languages. Please feel free to check out [ros_zeromq_tutorial](https://github.com/ravijo/ros_zeromq_tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROSTCP is an adapter that lets ROS send messages over TCP for topics; not for general use.

If you want a TCP socket, use the standard OS interface for creating a TCP socket.

There are many good tutorials about this online; here are a few:

- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/?utm_source=feedburner
- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-sock/
- [http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/%7Emoorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cayero](https://answers.ros.org/users/27919/cayero/) on 2016-12-21**:
Thank you for your answer, I'll on that. I found some helpful code. But client_node cannot connect to the server.  https://github.com/abhinavjain241/comm_tcp

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-26**:
I'm not familiar with that project, and I can't help you with it. I'd recommend that you ask a new question or open an issue on that repository. For either, I recommend that you include the specifics of your issue such as the exact commands and exact output.